# Android: Error When Overriding Method

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I'm following the page flipping tutorial from the official Android documents here:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

When overriding the getItem(int) method, I get this error:

> getItem(int) in 'ScreenSlidePagerAdapter class' clashes with getItem(int) in      'android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter'; attempting to use incompatible return   type.

My custom fragment class extends Fragment as in the tutorial.

To make sure I'm doing nothing wrong, I copy and pasted the example code to test it out (changing the names where required).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post your Activity code

Comment: Delete the method and add it this way :

Menu-Source-Overide/implement Methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your imports, in this method:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
```

you are probably returning

```
android.app.Fragment
```

when you should be returning

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

At the top of your class if it says:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

Remove that and make sure it says:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: Thanks. So simple (should have thought of that :P). Also, my custom fragment class was extending Fragment and I had to change it to extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment.